# 18.04.2 LTS - How to disconnect from wireless network, not turn off/on adapter

Tags: wireless, network-manager

In the network manager I see a check mark on the wireless network I am connected but I see no option to disconnect.  I only see options to:

1 - connect to a different network
2 - forget to current connection (requires re-credentialing)
3 - turn off wireless antennae/services/stack?

I expected a "right-click - disconnect" option but can't seem to locate this setting.  Searching online and here on Stack and all i find is how to disable the interface and re-enable it.

Is this not possible in Ubuntu 18.04?

I can only find how to turn the interface off/on which seems a tad heavy handed.

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
```

then...

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Comment: I use unity so it seems to be different.  I imagine you just have to uncheck, by clicking on it.  That should disconnect, and to connect just click on it again.  Unity still has the disconnect option under wireless, but the VPN work with clicking.  Could be wrong after reading PRATAP's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no GUI way..

But you can run `nmcli connection down $SSID`

[image]

from `man nmcli` some of the conent:

CONNECTION MANAGEMENT COMMANDS

```
   nmcli connection {show | up | down | modify | add | edit | clone | delete | monitor |
                    reload | load | import | export} [ARGUMENTS...]

down [id | uuid | path | apath] ID...
           Deactivate a connection from a device without preventing the device from further
           auto-activation. Multiple connections can be passed to the command.
```